# Class for manipulation Database which will works both on Android and Java desktop

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I want to test my logic at Desktop (to eliminate pain of waiting until everyting compiles and run on device/emulator...) so I made plain Java project.

I'm using ORMLite and SQLite on both desktop and Android. What is the best solution which will help me to call specific ORMLite methods depending on what am I running - Android or desktop?

Comment: Fighting a "pain" by creating another one. Sounds very reasonable.

Comment: When you will work on complex projects, you will see that removing unoptimized ADT for as long as you can from your development cycle is more reasonable than you think. I already done it with other technologies and for complex projects it needs to be done. Also, I don't see any "pain" in it, just relief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of ORMLite is to hide the underlying database from you.  That said, the Android environment is vastly different from JDBC so I don't see an easy way to use the same code on Android and desktop.

I would take a look at the [example programs](http://ormlite.com/docs/examples) to see how they differ.  That should help you write your different test code.

- [Simple, basic JDBC example](http://ormlite.com/docs/example-simple)
- [HelloAndroid example application](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-hello)